# Consistency of using the const qualifier

Tags: c

It seems that the `const` qualifier is often used inconsistently. Here is an example from another  answer [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204500/when-and-for-what-purposes-should-the-const-keyword-be-used-in-c-for-variables):

- Always use const for function parameters passed by reference where the function does not modify (or free) the data pointed to.

  ```
  int find(const int *data, size_t size, int value);
  ```

  ...Other uses are optional. For example, the parameters to a function within the function implementation can be marked as const.

So in the above, why would it be that and not, for example:

```
int find(const int *data, const size_t size, const int value);
```

Or:

```
int find(int *data, size_t size, int value);
```

It seems like perhaps 95% or more of the time, the parameters will not be modified. For example, if I had a math program (or anything functional for that matter), would the parameters all be:

```
int add_five_numbers(const int num1, const int num2, const int num3, ...)
```

Or when does it make sense to use the `const` qualifier and when is it just verbosity?

Comment: `when does it make sense to use the const qualifier?` answer: `use const for function parameters passed by reference where the function does not modify (or free) the data pointed to.`  `when is it just verbosity?` In other cases, when there parameter is passed by value.

Comment: @KamilCuk does that mean it's only necessary to add `const` on array/pointer parameters in the function? So `function(const int arr[], const int *ptr, int x)` if none of the three parameters are modified, or...?

Comment: `function(const int arr[])` and `function(const int *arr)` is _exactly_ the same. And yes, passing values using a pointer means passing parameters by reference to it, in C. Parameters are passed by value in C. So applying `const` to a _copy_ of that value is just a verbosity.

Comment: By specifying parameter `const` you are limiting what can be done with it inside function body. By specifying `data` as `const int *` you are saying that `data` is pointer to something that is `const int`. That means that while you are allowed to change `data`, you are not allowed to change the destination where it points to. Contrast that to specifying it as `int * const`, meaning that what what it points to is modifiable, but pointer itself is not. You can now assign, but can't do `++data` (something you can do if data is `const int*`).

Comment: Because the function receives a *Copy Of* `size_t size, int value` so no matter what you do with them in the function, the change will never be seen back in the caller (unless returned). So whether they are `const` qualified or not is immaterial.

Answer (score 1):

`const` should be used for paramters that are *pointers to data* on the caller side, when the pointers should not modify that data. This is called *const-correctness*.

Not that const correctness isn't just a matter of self-documenting code or preventing accidental slips by the programmer writing the function, but it also helps compiler optimization in terms of pointer aliasing. If the compiler knows that a pointer parameter can't modify for example some external linkage variable, it can rule out that scenario during code generation, perhaps leading to faster code.

It makes far less sense to make parameters passed by value `const`, since all parameters are a local copy anyway, and those cannot modify the original value at the caller-side.

Some people for some reason adapt a coding style where they make pass-by-value parameters `const` too and write things like `const int value`. There's no good rationale for doing so. Unlike the pointer case, this is just a matter of subjective coding style.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. So if I had a function that was obviously a read-only function, such as `print_object(Object* obj)` would you add in the `const` qualifier as well, or would that be deemed unnecessary: `print_object(const Object* obj)` ?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 `Object* obj` is a pointer to data on the caller side that shouldn't be modified by the function. Read this answer to find out if it should be const or not.

Comment: Re “If the compiler knows that a pointer parameter can't modify for example some external linkage variable, it can rule out that scenario during code generation, perhaps leading to faster code”: `const` cannot help with this, because C allows a pointer to `const` to be converted to pointer to non-`const` and used to modify the pointed-to object (if it was not defined with `const`, which the compiler cannot know from the parameter declaration), so there is no difference in `const void *a` and `void *a` in regard to what the compiler knows about whether `*a` may be modified.

Comment: It is not true there is no good rationale for declaring parameters `const`. If an author intends not to modify a parameter, declaring it `const` will catch errors in which their intent is violated, such as accidentally typing it instead of a similar name in some assignment or a later person modifying the function to modify the parameter when later in the function the original value is still needed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  "C allows a pointer to const to be converted to pointer to non-const and used to modify the pointed-to object" No, that's undefined behavior since no such conversion is defined by the standard. Similarly, the rules of effective type are poorly written when it comes to qualifiers and can't be relied on for making a lvalue access of a qualified effective type. And finally simple assignment (and thereby also initialization and parameter passing) labels conversions from qualified pointer to type to non-qualified pointer to type a constraint violation.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "such as accidentally typing it instead of a similar name" That's not a good reason. `void foo (int x){ x=1; // oops I typed x by mistake }` gcc: "warning: parameter 'x' set but not used". Doesn't really matter to me if the compiler tells me that, or if it tells me `error: assignment of read-only parameter 'x'`. In either case the code fails to compile cleanly.

Comment: Re “no such conversion is defined by the standard”: It is defined by C 6.3.2.3 7, which says any pointer to object type may be converted back to its original type and the result compares equal to the original pointer. If we have a `const int *p`, and the original object was not defined with `const`, then `p` was created by converting some pointer-to-non-`const` to a pointer to `const`. Converting it to pointer-to-non-`const` is a “back to its original type” conversion defined by 6.3.2.3 7.

Comment: Mistyping a name in the left operand of an assignment does not necessarily result in a warning because a parameter is set but not used because there may be other uses. Mistyping a name in the left operand of an assignment and so that the name is unintentionally the name of a const parameter does result in a warning.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Qualifiers are addressed by 6.3.2.3/2 "For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to the q-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers shall compare equal."  The opposite is not mentioned or defined by the standard, so it sorts under undefined behavior. §7 does not mention qualifiers nor does it mention de-referencing a qualified type through a non-qualified pointer. The whole thing is absent in the standard and it's a known language flaw.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, 6.3.2.2 2 is one paragraph that covers the conversion from non-const to const. Nonetheless, 6.3.2.3 7 also applies.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Assuming that 6.3.2.3/7 applies, then what will you do with the resulting non-qualified type? 6.7.3 explicitly states "If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined." Similarly you can't use them in simple assignment. And in case the object was originally declared as non-const qualified, the rules of effective type do not meaningfully mention qualifiers and apparently nobody knows how "effective type" works in regards of qualifiers.

Comment: You might like to add that const-qualifying a pass-by-value parameter in the prototype has no effect.

Comment: @Lundin: As I wrote, the situation is where an object is defined without `const`, a pointer to `const` is passed to the function, and the pointer is converted back to its original pointer-to-non-`const`. There is no attempt to modify an object **defined** with `const`. This has all been hashed out before and is settled.

Answer (score 1):

First, using `const` on pointer parameters is of great help because it gives *promises* to the call site.
For example:

```
int find(const int *data, size_t size, int value);
...
int t[100]={ ... };
int pos=find(t, 100, 123);
// I'm certain t[] still contains the initial values
// (except in case of an ugly const-cast, but in such
//  a case no one could ever trust anything...)
```

Moreover, suppose you have:

```
const int *t=...;
int pos=find(t, 100, 123);
```

If the first parameter of `find()` is `const int *data`, this call is correct, but if this parameter is `int *data`, then the call will be rejected because the function has the *ability* to mutate the pointed-to data (even if it does not), but the `t` variable is not allowed to mutate the pointed-to data.

Now, when it comes to passing simple types (by value), the fact that the parameter will be modified or not inside the function does not change *anything* at the call site; it's just an implementation detail of the function itself, so there is no need to make the prototype harder to read.
For example:

```
int find_A(const int *data, const size_t size, const int value);
int find_B(const int *data, size_t size, int value)
{
  size-=10; // stupid, just for the sake of the example
  value+=5; // stupid, just for the sake of the example
  ...
}
...
int t[100]={ ... };
size_t sz=100;
int val=123;
int pos_A=find_A(t, sz, val); // sz and val won't be mutated
int pos_B=find_B(t, sz, val); // sz and val will no more be mutated
```

Actually, when calling `find_B()` (or `find_A()`) `size` and `value` are *copies* of `sz` and `val`; these copies could be mutated, that will never alter the original variables.
Moreover, as far as I know, `const` parameters are ignored in the declaration (not in the definition); i.e. you can define

```
int find(const int * const data, const size_t size, const int value)
{
  ...
}
```

and provide whether this declaration

```
int find(const int * const data, const size_t size, const int value);
```

or this one

```
int find(const int *data, size_t size, int value);
```

it won't change anything at the call site.

Note also that, when considering again the pointer parameter, the same consideration applies.
The `const` *before* the star means that the pointed-to data cannot be mutated, and this is very important and meaningful, but the `const` *after* the star means that the pointer *itself* cannot be mutated (i.e. cannot point towards something else once initialised).
For example, with `const int * const data` you cannot perform `*data=8` (leading `const`) and you can no more perform `++data` (trailing `const`).
On the other hand, with `const int *data` you still cannot perform `*data=8` (leading `const`) but you are allowed to perform `++data` (*no* trailing `const`).
And, of course, this last operation won't move any pointer at the call site (for the same reason as for `size` and `value`).

So, in the end, you should only use *meaningful* (leading) `const` qualifiers on pointer parameters to state that the pointed-to data will not be mutated, thus enabling the use of this function on `const` qualified data.

Comment: `const` on pointers is more of a promise or suggestion in C, not a guarantee, since C allows a pointer-to-const to be converted to a pointer-to-non-const and used to modify the pointed-to-object, provided it was not defined with `const`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree with you, that's why I wrote about const-casting that can annihilate the *guarantee*. May be *guarantee* is not the correct word (too strong meaning), I'm not confident about my English, sorry about that. I will switch to *promise* as you suggest, thanks.